# Parallax effect on 3 layers footer using native CSS

Tags: css, footer, parallax

I'm trying to create a parallax effect on a 3 layers footer, only using CSS. My foreground contains trees, my intermediate layer mountains, and my background the Sun, and I want them to scroll at a different speed when we scroll down or up the page.
I've tried many different parallax tutorials, but didn't find out how to do it.

HTML :

```
<section>
  <p>Page content</p>
</section>
<footer>
  <div id="hills"></div>
  <div id="trees"></div>
</footer>
```

CSS :

```
section {
  height : 100vh;
}

footer {
    background-color: #57cc99;
    padding: 1em .5em;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25vw;
}

footer::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    top: -25vw;
    right: 25%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fac301;
}

footer #trees, footer #hills{
    position: absolute;
    height: 830px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
footer #hills{
    bottom: 0%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 2001.1 829.07'%3E%3Cg id='svg-hills' data-name='hills'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23f0e9de' d='M1874.1,119.74c-88.17,87.92-133.32,152.86-240,200-47.49,21-88,26.61-125.33,32-94.85,13.69-170.67,1.59-259.6-12.62a1398.38,1398.38,0,0,1-140.4-30.05c-73.58-19.69-95.58-31.92-146.11-47.55C937.47,253.74,823,219.7,675.44,223.74c-57,1.56-124.78,3.42-207.93,30.57-111.09,36.28-132.74,79.54-260.07,110.76-71.57,17.55-120,22.67-120,22.67C52.74,391.41,23.63,392,0,392.57v436.5H2001.1V0C1954.63,39.44,1908.24,85.7,1874.1,119.74Z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E") bottom center no-repeat;
}

footer #trees{
    bottom: 99%;
    z-index: 0;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 2000 465.59'%3E%3Cg id='Calque_1-2' data-name='Calque 1'%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%2357cc99' points='1989.28 0 1979.43 26.47 1989.45 25.66 1973.18 43.23 1937.26 139.71 1922.64 100.47 1909.69 96.99 1918.19 88.5 1910.55 67.98 1883.13 141.62 1902.08 141.06 1872.22 170.91 1858 209.11 1722.93 270.17 1708.6 206.54 1681.92 197.08 1702.48 179.36 1687.81 114.21 1658.27 245.41 1633.21 175.1 1607.17 248.17 1587.71 144.28 1574.17 116.59 1583.36 121.09 1574.17 72.04 1542.19 242.75 1571.82 221.59 1529.46 310.67 1519.85 361.96 1423.08 405.71 1411.23 351.68 1401.77 348.54 1409.11 342.01 1403.13 314.7 1387.42 386.39 1395.44 391.81 1385.13 396.83 1378.8 425.72 1304.42 459.34 1050.11 402.97 1040.16 365.79 1009.3 325.25 1030.02 327.9 999.26 212.91 990.55 245.46 1000.06 254.97 987.07 258.45 954.1 381.69 889.92 367.46 875.28 312.74 840.58 279.32 867.25 282.73 836.79 168.85 824.63 164.85 833.58 156.86 825.03 124.92 801.95 211.21 825.51 225.89 796.96 229.85 768.8 335.11 760.71 304.84 740.35 290.8 755.08 283.8 736.11 212.91 723.63 259.57 733.48 257.84 721.14 268.88 705.69 326.62 507.9 282.78 494.67 233.34 459.45 191.27 484.6 195.67 454.85 84.5 427.91 185.2 410.96 136.1 381 222.9 354.64 124.38 324.61 118.57 346.38 93.48 331.15 36.55 297.73 161.47 324.69 147.96 285.78 206.11 278.85 232.01 248.02 225.17 245.65 216.32 220.99 181.67 237.92 187.4 224.4 136.88 214.08 119.04 220.65 122.84 213.81 97.3 197.86 156.94 208.98 152.22 193.58 172.94 183.43 210.85 40.37 179.14 21.55 109.28 3.5 104.43 16.69 91.25 0 29.32 0 170.19 0 260.52 0 465.59 1290.59 465.59 1332.61 465.59 2000 465.59 2000 357.83 2000 308.2 2000 289.84 2000 144.92 2000 28.78 1989.28 0'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E") bottom center no-repeat;

}
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/SuperOuf/pen/eYLvNyP

Thanks in advance for your help

I tried to follow multiple tutorials for parallax, but never applied to footer layers.